# TV app in Catalina does not search in local library

Tags: itunes, catalina, movie, tv.app

Actually problem/issue pointed in the title of the question.
When I try to search something in the search field in the up right corner app just shows results from the store, not local library.

As a result I cannot find my own movies.
Anybody can confirm such behaviour?
Can give a hint for workaround/fix?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Use the Show Filter Field option to search your library:

1. Click Library at the top of the window
2. Click View in the menubar and select Show Filter Field
3. Use the filter field to search your library

[image: TV app (macOS Catalina) with Show Filter Field option enabled.]